# Inserting images in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

I have an AngularJS project (first one) with the MEAN stack.

My question pertains to adding images.

In order to add an image, the first one, I had to do all this:

Create as a service a new file named images.js in /public/system/services/

Code for this service is:

```
'use strict';

//Image service
angular.module('mean.system').factory('ImageSol', [
    function() {
        return {
            logo : 'public/system/assets/img/logo-sol.png'
        };
    }
]);
```

After that, modify my IndexController accordingly like so:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.system').controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'Global', 'ImageSol', function ($scope, Global, ImageSol) {
    $scope.global = Global;
    $scope.logo = ImageSol.logo;
}]);
```

In the actual HTML, I had to declare the IndexController as a data-ng-controller and insert the image href as a ng-src={{logo}}

Do I have to create a scope and declare the path to the image there every single time?
Is there a mixture or swig-like method of just saying {{imagename}} and it automatically finding my image and inserting it as a link?

I really loved using Mixture (mixture.io) and their magic assets feature and I was wondering if I could have something like this with angular.

Comment: Yes - they're called helper functions. Write them.

Comment: if your path is going to change, thats is the best way, if you are just displaying 1 picture per html element just set the path in your ng.src